# populating jframe after clicking submit

Tags: java, swing, button, jpanel, submit

I'm writign a program for homework and have gotten most of it to work except one item (besides the actual "view" of the screen displays poorly).  I'm doing some calculations based on user input, using text fields and combo boxes.  I've converted any text to integers.  The problem is, when I click on the submit button, it is supposed to do the calculations and then display the results.  When the program first opens, the results display 0.  Any help would be appreciated. It does compile with no errors and will run.  Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.Graphics.*;
    import java.awt.Font.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.text.*;

    public class tripManager extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        //declare variables
            Color teal = new Color(0,128,128);
            Color wheat = new Color(245,222,179);
            Font myFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,14);
            Font titleFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD, 20);
            private int oGallons;
            private double oPerMileGas;
            private int oRefuel;
            private int oOilChange;
            private double oTotalTripCost;
            private int oVehicle;
            private int oCMileage;
            private int oOMileage;
            private double oGasType;
            private double oGasCost;
            private int oMiles;
            private double oOilCost;



        //construct components
        JPanel titleJPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel companyJLabel = new JLabel("TRAVELOR'S GASOLINE CALCULATOR");
            JLabel companyAddressJLabel = new JLabel("11333 Main Street, Zephyrhills, FL 33542");
            JLabel descriptionJLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to the Travelor's Gasoline Calculator.  This application");
            JLabel descriptionJLabel2 = new JLabel("will calculate the total cost of your trip, breaking it down by");
            JLabel descriptionJLabel3 = new JLabel("cost per mile and maintenance costs.");

        JPanel inputJPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel milesTravelJLabel = new JLabel("Enter total number of trip miles: ");
                TextField tripMiles = new TextField(8);
            JLabel currentMileageJLabel = new JLabel("Enter current mileage on your vehicle: ");
                TextField cMileage = new TextField(8);
            JLabel oilChangeMileageJLabel = new JLabel("Enter mileage of last oil change: ");
                TextField oMileage = new TextField(8);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            Button  clearButton = new Button("Clear");
            Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
            Button quitButton = new Button("Exit");

        JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel gallonsUsedLabel = new JLabel("Total Gallons of gas needed for trip: "+ oGallons+" Gallons");
            JLabel costPerMileLabel = new JLabel("Total cost of gas per mile: $"+oPerMileGas);
            JLabel refuelLabel = new JLabel("Total number of times to refuel: "+oRefuel);
            JLabel oilChangesNeedLabel = new JLabel("Total number of oil changes needed: "+oOilChange);
            JLabel totalCostLabel = new JLabel("Total travel cost is: $"+oTotalTripCost);

        //construct drop box
        JPanel dropJPanel = new JPanel();
            JComboBox vehicleCombo = new JComboBox();
            JComboBox beginLocation = new JComboBox();
            JComboBox endLocation = new JComboBox();
            JComboBox gasType = new JComboBox();



        public tripManager()
        {
            //set layouts for frame and panels
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                titleJPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
                inputJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                outputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
                dropJPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
                buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

            //add components to titleJPanel
            titleJPanel.add(companyJLabel);
            titleJPanel.add(companyAddressJLabel);
            titleJPanel.add(descriptionJLabel);
            titleJPanel.add(descriptionJLabel2);
            titleJPanel.add(descriptionJLabel3);


            //add components to inputJPanel
            inputJPanel.add(milesTravelJLabel);
            inputJPanel.add(tripMiles);
            inputJPanel.add(currentMileageJLabel);
            inputJPanel.add(cMileage);
            inputJPanel.add(oilChangeMileageJLabel);
            inputJPanel.add(oMileage);

            //add components to output Panel
            outputPanel.add(gallonsUsedLabel);
            outputPanel.add(costPerMileLabel);
            outputPanel.add(refuelLabel);
            outputPanel.add(oilChangesNeedLabel);
            outputPanel.add(totalCostLabel);

            //add components to button Panel
            buttonPanel.add(clearButton);
            buttonPanel.add(submitButton);
            buttonPanel.add(quitButton);



            //populate JCombo Boxes
            vehicleCombo.addItem("compact");
            vehicleCombo.addItem("mid");
            vehicleCombo.addItem("luxury");
            vehicleCombo.addItem("SUV");
            vehicleCombo.addActionListener(this);
            vehicleCombo.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arrow to display list of vehicles");
            beginLocation.addItem("New York City");
            beginLocation.addItem("Seatle");
            beginLocation.addItem("Los Angelos");
            beginLocation.addItem("Chicago");
            beginLocation.addItem("Atlanta");
            beginLocation.addItem("Tampa");
            beginLocation.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arrow to display list of cities");
            beginLocation.addItem("New York City");
            endLocation.addItem("Seatle");
            endLocation.addItem("Los Angelos");
            endLocation.addItem("Chicago");
            endLocation.addItem("Atlanta");
            endLocation.addItem("Tampa");
            endLocation.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arrow to display list of cities");
            gasType.addItem("leaded");
            gasType.addItem("unleaded");
            gasType.addItem("super unleaded");
            gasType.addItem("diesel");
            gasType.setToolTipText("Click the drop-down arrow to display list of gas types");

            //add components to dropPanel
            dropJPanel.add(vehicleCombo);
            dropJPanel.add(beginLocation);
            dropJPanel.add(endLocation);
            dropJPanel.add(gasType);

            //add panels to frame
            add(titleJPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(inputJPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(dropJPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(outputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

            //initiate buttons
            clearButton.addActionListener(this);
            submitButton.addActionListener(this);
            quitButton.addActionListener(this);

            //add action listener to combo boxes
            vehicleCombo.addActionListener(this);
            beginLocation.addActionListener(this);
            endLocation.addActionListener(this);
            gasType.addActionListener(this);


        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            tripManager f = new tripManager();
            f.setBounds(400,400,600,600);
            f.setTitle("TRAVELOR'S GASOLINE CALCULATOR");
            f.setVisible(true);
        }//end of main

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        if(e.getSource()==clearButton)
        {
            tripMiles.setText("");
            cMileage.setText("");
            oMileage.setText("");
            tripMiles.requestFocus();
        }

        else if(e.getSource()==submitButton)
        {
            String arg = e.getActionCommand();

            if (arg=="submit")
            {
            //vehicle combo selections
            if (arg =="compact")
                oVehicle = 13;
            else if (arg=="mid")
                oVehicle = 18;
            else if (arg=="luxury")
                oVehicle = 15;
            else if (arg == "SUV")
                oVehicle = 23;
        //gas type combo selections
            if (arg =="leaded")
                oGasType = 2.50;
            else if (arg == "unleaded")
                oGasType = 2.90;
            else if (arg == "super unleaded")
                oGasType = 3.00;
            else if (arg == "diesel")
                oGasType = 4.00;
        //get number of miles
        oMiles = Integer.parseInt(tripMiles.getText());
        oGasCost = ((oMiles/oVehicle) * oGasType);

        //calcculate gallons used
        oGallons = oMiles/oVehicle;

        //calculate cost per mile
        oPerMileGas = oGasCost/oMiles;

        //calculate number times to refuel
        oRefuel = oGallons/oVehicle;

        //calculate oil changes needed
        if ((oCMileage - oOMileage)+oMiles >3000)
        {
            oOilChange = (oCMileage-oOMileage+oMiles)/3000;
        }
        else
        {
            oOilChange = 0;
        }
        oOilCost = oOilChange * 30;

        //calculate total trip cost
        oTotalTripCost = oOilCost * oGasCost;

        Component outputPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel gallonsUsedLabel = new JLabel("Total Gallons of gas needed for trip: " +oGallons+" Gallons");
        JLabel costPerMileLabel = new JLabel("Total cost of gas per mile: $"+oPerMileGas);
        JLabel refuelLabel = new JLabel("Total number of times to refuel: "+oRefuel);
        JLabel oilChangesNeedLabel = new JLabel("Total number of oil changes needed: "+oOilChange);
        JLabel totalCostLabel = new JLabel("Total travel cost is: $"+oTotalTripCost);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 2) Don't set the size or bounds of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare Strings as that checks for object identity which is not what you want. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Also you're doing nothing to check any of the JComboBoxes. The arg String has nothing to do with the combobox but instead is going to be the text of the button pressed, and while important tells you nothing about what combo box item has been selected. Check the selected item in each of the comboboxes. If you're confused on this point, please have a look at the combo box tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll do some more research and go through the tutorials again.

Comment: @SelliS: that sounds like a great plan. Best of luck!